# how to textalign in middle with css?

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to align my to atags in the centre:

```
|     anchor1       |      anchor2       |
```

this is my jquery now:

```
<div id="main">
    <a id="fancybox-manual-c" href="javascript:void(0);">anchor1</a>
    <a class="watchvideo_new" href="javascript:void(0);">anchor2</a>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#main").css({
            "border-color": "black",
            "border-width": "1px",
            "border-style": "solid"
        });

        $("#main").width(340);

        $("#fancybox-manual-c").width(185);

        $(".watchvideo_new").width(185);
        $(".watchvideo_new").css('background', 'white');
    }
        );

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a{
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

Something like the above should work.

The default `display` of an `a` element is `inline`, so you need to change it to be able to set the width.

One thing about `display:inline-block` is you'll also get an extra 4px generally, and this is because it counts the space in between elements as an actual space.

Comment: +1 right, whereas my answer centers whole content of `#main` to center.  But I guess it tend to be aligned vertical.

Comment: @user603007 - always test to be sure. IE<8 don't handle `block` -> `inline-block`, but they do allow `inline` -> `inline-block` so you should have no troubles (http://caniuse.com/inline-block). There may also be a problem with `min-width`: http://caniuse.com/minmaxwh

Answer (score 0):

```
 a{
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    min-width: 100px;
   }
```